# Fantasy book where the female protagonist is placed under magical protection by an older woman (while sleeping)

Tags: story-identification

The book I'm looking for (which I read circa 1980-1990) revolves around The Hunt and is set in a old English type of countryside.

I remember the main character was a girl with gifts and at the end of the book a woman does something while she's sleeping 'to protect' her.  After the woman protects the girl she walks away making sure not to step on the shadow of the leaves that stuck to the window.

Comment: Was this paperback or hardback? A full-blown novel, or a story mixed in with others? Can you describe the front cover to any degree?

Comment: DO you remember any character names? What "gifts" did the girl have? To what use did she put these gifts? Why didn't she step on the shadows?

Comment: First thought was [I Shall Wear Midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Shall_Wear_Midnight) but that was published in 2010.

Comment: For a second there it sounded like the Elenium by Eddings but them it just so wasn't....I though I had one there for a moment!

Answer (score 2):

Thorns- Eurasia: The Fifteenth Century, by Tanith Lee from her collection Red as Blood, or Tales from the Sisters Grimmer (1983). Not certain about this exact story (I haven't read it in ~20 years) but it sounds like one of Lee's retellings of classical fairy tales, particularly this story, which is the re-telling of Sleeping Beauty.

Sadly, I can not seem to locate a description of the story, and I have no idea what happened to my copy of the book.

Comment: I have this book and I reread the story, but it doesn't really match the description. It's a (very dark!) retelling of Sleeping Beauty and there's nothing in it about the shadows of leaves on the window.